# GRE geometry questions about finding the angle between a side of a triangle and a circumradius

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

I am struggling with reconciling the fact that all the middle lines are the same length with the fact that the angles aren't the same.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Never, ever, ever assume pictures are drawn to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to draw the figure.  Each of the triangles with peak at $D$ is isosceles, so the base angles are equal.  That gives $\angle DBC=20^\circ$ so $\angle CDB=140^\circ$.  $ADC$ is equilateral so $\angle CDA=60^\circ$.  That leaves $\angle ADB=160^\circ$  Now just draw a circle, put a protractor at the middle, and draw the radii from the center at those angles.  You will have the desired triangle.